# difference between CV_RETR_LIST,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am using cvFindContour function of opencv and in it there is a parameter RETR_TYPE means retrivel type,hence I am not getting what is the difference between `CV_RETR_LIST`, `CV_RETR_TREE`, `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`?

Comment: Here is a link to the book [OpenCV](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA236&lpg=PA236&dq=CV_RETR_LIST,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL&source=bl&ots=hSF68jiEN9&sig=EukC6H9XafAm89zOkkw7UiFWvAc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pnQOT87GH-mimQWjn8TDAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=CV_RETR_LIST%2CCV_RETR_TREE%2CCV_RETR_EXTERNAL&f=false) which explains the differences (pg 236-237)

Comment: You can find more details on this article : http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2013/01/contours-5-hierarchy.html

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for `findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#findcontours).

The main difference is in the `hierarchy` that is returned (giving the relationship between one contour and the next).

- `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` gives "outer" contours, so if you have (say) one contour enclosing another (like concentric circles), only the outermost is given.
- `CV_RETR_LIST` gives all the contours and doesn't even bother calculating the `hierarchy` -- good if you only want the contours and don't care whether one is nested inside another.
- `CV_RETR_CCOMP` gives contours and organises them into outer and inner contours. Every contour is either the outline of an object, or the outline of an object *inside* another object (i.e. hole). The `hierarchy` is adjusted accordingly. This can be useful if (say) you want to find all holes.
- `CV_RETR_TREE` calculates the full hierarchy of the contours. So you can say that object1 is nested 4 levels deep within object2 and object3 is also nested 4 levels deep.

Answer (score 5):

From `imgproc.cpp`:

```
//! mode of the contour retrieval algorithm
enum RetrievalModes {
    /** retrieves only the extreme outer contours. It sets `hierarchy[i][2]=hierarchy[i][3]=-1` for
    all the contours. */
    RETR_EXTERNAL  = 0,
    /** retrieves all of the contours without establishing any hierarchical relationships. */
    RETR_LIST      = 1,
    /** retrieves all of the contours and organizes them into a two-level hierarchy. At the top
    level, there are external boundaries of the components. At the second level, there are
    boundaries of the holes. If there is another contour inside a hole of a connected component, it
    is still put at the top level. */
    RETR_CCOMP     = 2,
    /** retrieves all of the contours and reconstructs a full hierarchy of nested contours.*/
    RETR_TREE      = 3,
    RETR_FLOODFILL = 4 //!<
};
```

**OpenCV 2.4.13**