# filling random shapes using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to create an application where I need to fill in irregular shapes, such as lips and eye balls.

What I tried to do was I extracted the CLM points.  Next,  I tried the floodfilling function in OpenCV, but I wasn't able to do it for random shapes.

After, I tried the `drawContours` function and filled using negative thickness, and I got results as below.

[image]

Can anyone give suggestions for getting better filling results and tracking CLM points?

Comment: Showing the code you actually tried would help.  Also, it seems that you are detecting contours in a hierarchy.  Try detecting the outer most contour, then fill in the contour.  Use the `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` flag when detecting the contours.   It looks like you have a set of contours that describes the outer and inner lip, and it's filling everything in between because this is considered as one contour.  Here's a useful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830619/difference-between-cv-retr-list-cv-retr-tree-cv-retr-external

Comment: Thanks for your response. To make it clear, i have **not extracted** any of the contours using **findcontours** function for which there are several hierarchies. I created my own contour using the CLM points for lips and used the drawcontour function.

Comment: The code is as in the link below    [lipscode](https://gauthamjayendhar.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/lipstick-code/)